# Train OLS model with pandas concurrently

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to train multiple OLS models (in fact, the number is about 500 in total) with pandas. Could I do this in a batched fashion?

Here is a simplified case, in which I want to train 5 models, say m1, m2, m3, m4, m5.
Each of the models is with 4 degrees' freedom.
Instead of training m1 to m5 sequentially, I want to organize all the Y data into a `DataFrame` like

```
def makeDataFrame():
    return pandas.DataFrame(
        data={
            'm1':range(10),
            'm2':range(10), 
            'm3':range(10, 20), 
            'm4':range(20, 30), 
            'm5':range(30, 40)})

Y = makeDataFrame()
```

:

```
   m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
0   0   0  10  20  30
1   1   1  11  21  31
2   2   2  12  22  32
3   3   3  13  23  33
4   4   4  14  24  34
5   5   5  15  25  35
6   6   6  16  26  36
7   7   7  17  27  37
8   8   8  18  28  38
9   9   9  19  29  39
```

And then collect all the X corresponding to each Y into a panel

```
X = pandas.Panel({'A':makeDataFrame(), 'B':makeDataFrame(), 'C':makeDataFrame()})
```

Then use `pandas.ols(y = Y, x = X)` to get five models for m1-m5 concurrently (all 5 models are of the form Y ~ A + B + C + intercept).
From my experiments, the above codes cannot satisfy my requirements.
Any alternatives?

Is it possible with Pandas?

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are trying to organize the computation?  Which libraries are you using, apart from pandas?

Comment: `Y` and `X` seem to consist of the same data here (generated using `makeDataFrame`). Is this intended?

Comment: @eickenberg no, the real data is not necessarily equal for X and Y. Thanks.

Comment: Could you make this explicit? I am having difficulties understanding what you are trying to do. As far as I get it you seem to have several models for one target? (In the case of one model for several targets there definitely is a solution)

Comment: @eickenberg Can I take the target same as model here? If so, I'm trying to train different models. Instead of training the models (5 in my running example) one by one, I want to batch them, and train all the models with one ols invocation expecting this can speed up the process (anyway, I have 500+ models to train). You can take the columns as a dimension to describe different models, and indexes as the data. Thank you very much for your time! "In the case of one model for several targets there definitely is a solution" And could you please write down your thoughts as an answer?